# Fullcalendar not showing Google Calendar data

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api, fullcalendar-5

So i follow the documents and some Youtube tutorials for connecting the Google Calendar API to Fullcalendar but the only thing i'm getting is the blank Fullcalendar view. There are no events displaying from my Google Calendar. My API and Google Calendar ID are set up correctly. Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <link href='lib/main.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <script src='lib/main.js'></script>
    <script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
        var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          initialView: 'dayGridMonth'
        });
        calendar.render();
});

let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
  plugins: [ googleCalendarPlugin ],
  googleCalendarApiKey: 'XXXXXX',
  events: {
    googleCalendarId: 'YYYYYY@group.calendar.google.com'
  }
});
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='calendar'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? Do you see any network request in the browser's network log, going to the google calendar API?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo I guess you edited this to try and hide the API key. Just FYI it doesn't fully hide it, because it's still visible in the revision history, accessible by clicking on the "edited X minutes ago" link just above your name, which takes you to https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67322186/revisions . OP could delete the question and re-create it, that would hide it better (although SO admins would still have access to the info, if they retained a link to the question, but at least it wouldn't be public any more).

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 

rooster.html:17 Uncaught ReferenceError: Calendar is not defined

Comment: @ADyson Thanks, I know it doesn't, I actually flagged the question for deletion and edited it silently to not draw attention to it if anyone happens across it in the mean time...

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you've written the code starting with `let calendar = new Calendar` even though you've already defined the calendar in the previous lines. There are two main issues:

a) That bit of code won't work because you didn't prefix it with `FullCalendar.` (as per your first calendar declaration) so it can't find the `Calendar` class outside the `FullCalendar` namespace. Additionally `calendarEl` isn't in scope there either because the code is outside the `DOMContentLoaded` event handler.

b) It makes no sense anyway - why would you try and declare two calendars in one page, both attached to the same HTML element? It won't achieve anything good. You need to put the google calendar-related options inside the first calendar declaration. (You shouldn't need the `plugins` option unless you're using an ES6 build system, which you aren't.)

Something like this will make more sense and should work (assuming you've set the google calendar up correctly as per the documentation):

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

  var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    googleCalendarApiKey: 'XXXXXX',
    events: {
      googleCalendarId: 'YYYYYY@group.calendar.google.com'
    }        
  });

  calendar.render();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi @ADyson, please can you check my question on FullCalendar? Thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67384812/full-calendar-styling-not-correct-after-import